# Intercambio de iconos y texto

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4, botón

¿Cómo podría intercambiar un `<button type="button" class="fa fa-user btn btn-white btn-sm>` por `<button type="button" class="btn btn-white btn-sm>`? Es decir que en lugar de que aparezca el icono aparezca el texto.

Código:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row justify-content-between">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
    <button type="button" class="fa fa-user btn btn-white btn-sm "></button>Ver Imagen
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
    <button type="button" class="fa fa-user btn btn-white btn-sm "></button>Ver Imagen
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
    <button type="button" class="fa fa-user btn btn-white btn-sm "></button>Ver Imagen
  </div>
</div>
```

Lo que estoy o quiero intentar es que se oculte el icono para que solo aparezca el button con texto.

Comment: Hola @soniky. Por favor, edita tu pregunta incluyendo lo que has intentado y donde te ha fallado. Para que puedas ver como editar la pregunta y dejarla correcta mira [tour] y [ask]. Además conseguirás tu primera medalla!

Comment: Hola soniky, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y ganar tu primera medalla). No termina de quedar claro cuál es el problema que tienes, si ya sabes que lo que tienes que hacer es quitar las clases `fa fa-user`, ¿qué es lo que te lo impide? Estás poniendo la solución mejor en la propia pregunta (quitar las clases en el html). Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar tus preguntas. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Copias la clase por ejemplo para `<i class='fa fa-times'></i>` en tu css pones

```
i.fa-times:before{
   content: "Cerrar";
   font-family : "Arial";
}
```

Comment: y pregunta mejor, porque fue difícil entenderte.

Comment: Hola @JorgeBowen. A una pregunta como esta, que no explica nada de lo que ha intentado ni buscado  (en resumen, nada de trabajo) no hay que contestar, hay que esperar que editen la pregunta ampliando la información. Mira [answer] para que veas como y cuando responder a una pregunta